# Selenium (python) how to best handle a page anomaly

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping pages of the Italian website publishing new laws (Gazzetta Ufficiale) to save the final page which holds the law text.

I have a loop that builds a list of the pages to download and am attaching a fully working cose sample which shows the problem I'm running in (the sample is not looped I am just doing two "gets".

What is the best way to handle the rare page which does not show the "Visualizza" (show) button but goes straight to the desired full text?

Hope the code is pretty self explanatory and commented. Thank you in advance and super happy 2022!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/bob/Documents/work/scraper/scrape_gu/chromedriver")

# showing the "normal" behaviour
driver.get(
    "https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/atto/vediMenuHTML?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-01-02&atto.codiceRedazionale=20A07300&tipoSerie=serie_generale&tipoVigenza=originario"
)
# this page has a "Visualizza" button, find it and click it.
bottoni = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corpo_export"]/div/input[1]')
    )
)
time.sleep(5)  # just to see the "normal" result with the "Visualizza" button
bottoni[0].click()  # now click it  and this shows the desired final webpage
time.sleep(5)  # just to see the "normal" desired result

# but unfortunately some pages directly get to the end result WITHOUT the "Visualizza" button.
# as an example see the following get
# showing the "normal" behaviour
driver.get(
    "https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/atto/vediMenuHTML?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-01-02&atto.codiceRedazionale=20A07249&tipoSerie=serie_generale&tipoVigenza=originario"
) # get a law page
time.sleep(
    5
)  #  as you can see we are now on the final desired full page WITHOUT the Visualizza button
# hence the following code, identical to that above will fail and timeout
bottoni = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="corpo_export"]/div/input[1]')
    )
)
time.sleep(5)  # just to see the result
bottoni[0].click()  # and this shows the desired final webpage

# and the program abends with the following message
#  File "/Users/bob/Documents/work/scraper/scrape_gu/temp.py", line 33, in <module>
#    bottoni = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
#  File "/Users/bob/opt/miniconda3/envs/scraping/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
#    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
#  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception with a `try` and `except` block - If there is no button extract the text directly - [Handling Exeptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
...
urls = [
    'https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/atto/vediMenuHTML?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-01-02&atto.codiceRedazionale=20A07300&tipoSerie=serie_generale&tipoVigenza=originario',
    'https://www.gazzettaufficiale.it/atto/vediMenuHTML?atto.dataPubblicazioneGazzetta=2021-01-02&atto.codiceRedazionale=20A07249&tipoSerie=serie_generale&tipoVigenza=originario'
   ]


data = []

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        bottoni = WebDriverWait(driver,1).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, '//input[@value="Visualizza"]')
            )
        )
        bottoni.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print('no bottoni -')

    finally:
        data.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//body').text)

driver.close()
print(data)
...
```

Comment: Please no bare except, catch the specific exception instead.

Comment: @Loïc : Do you mean the `except TimeoutException:` to be aware, that it is caused by the `wait` and not by another one?

Comment: Yes, catching specifically ```selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException``` to make sure that you don't catch other exceptions. For example you could catch KeyboardInterrupt exception in a bare except, preventing the script from stopping when ctrl + c is pressed.

Comment: Definitely useful to be able to go into the exact cause - already added and many thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thank you very very much for the solution and also for the very instructive comments. Learning a lot thanks to good people like you all. Happy 2022 !!!!

Comment: Maybe a minor enhancement to your code would be moving the data.append statements in a finally: block after the except: block?

Comment: Tried your code and it works, but is there a better way than just waiting full ten seconds?

Comment: @RobertAlexander : Also a good point, edited example and added `finally:` - In principle, you can also reduce the waiting time considerably, 10 seconds is indeed quite long and website is responding quiet fast.

Answer (score 1):

First, using selenium for this task is overkill.

You'd be able to do the same thing using [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) coupled with [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), except that would be much faster and easier to code.

Now to get back to your question, there are a few solutions.

The simplest would be :

- Catch the timeout exception : if the button isn't found, then go straight to parsing the law.
- Check if the button is present : `!driver.findElements(By.id("corpo_export")).isEmpty()`, before either clicking on it, or parsing the web page.

But then again, you'd have a much easier time getting rid of selenium and using beautifulsoup instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Loic. The above is just a very small snippet of a much more complex code to handle an horribly complex and irregular website in which a lot of drop down boxes, buttons and other stuff must be simulated. Being totally ignorant I started out with Selenium and found it easier to understand than my old attempts with BS4. Will definitely look into your suggestions. Happy 2022.